# Error running micarray_recorder from matrix-creator-hal

Tags: matrix-creator

I've compiled the demos for matrix-creator-hal and I'm trying to run micarray_recorder.  It fails because the call to GetFPGAFrequency returns zeros.  (This causes a floating point exception because it's trying to divide by zero.)

Does anyone know what the call GetFPGAFrequency does and why it's wouldn't be returning the correct values?